# Moving all Joomla site's data to a new-clean installed one?

Tags: joomla3.0

Can I move all current Joomla site's data (articles, urls, menus,contacts, users. extensions+ their content) to a new installed joomla without loosing anything?

my website has lot of problems and I want to install a fresh Joomla and then import all of the old data to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SP Transfer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sp-transfer) or similar to transfer core content (articles, categories, menus, contacts, users etc) from one Joomla installation to another but there's no easy way to transfer extensions except perhaps to reinstall them and copy across any relevant database tables.

Another approach might be to try the "Reinstall Joomla core files" option in Components -> Joomla Update (run a backup using Akeeba Backup or similar before trying this step) to reset Joomla.